# NodeJS Express app not working as expected - showing it's content instead of executing

Tags: node.js, express, plesk, express-generator

I've created a node webapp with express-generator, this app works great on localhost.
But as soon as i move my app to the server and surf the domain, it shows the content of the app.js file instead of executing it, i've tried to reproduce this issue on localhost without success.
I've also checked the configuration of the web server, looks good so far.

If i run the app on localhost, the app.js file gets executed without any problems, but on the webserver the file content is shown only and nothing executes.

This only happens with the app.js file, any other file of the app works fine, views are rendered and routes are working.

I'm grateful for any help!

Some additional information:

OS: Windows Server 2016 Datecenter
Node 12
Node app deployed via Plesk Obsidian

Answer (score 0):

This is solved, it looks like this is a problem with iisnode since the app works as it should when it runs as a service